# Problems with the appearance of the drop-down list on iOS devices

Tags: jquery, ios, input, shared-libraries, dropdown

I need the help of a person who can give me the advice about behavior of this input on ios devices or someone who has used this library http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ or may have previously encountered a similar problem.

I use this library on my website. It works well on androids and windows devices. Problems arise when you try to run the search on iOS devices(tested on iphone 8), namely, there is no drop-down list with options from which you select the one you need, which should appear after the two characters entered. It will appear only after you delete the last 2 characters ("er") from the entered word (for example,"Dexter").

I broke my whole head studying the code of this library, at first I thought that the problem was in the triggered event(keyup, keydown, keypress, onchange), that ios conflicts with it, tried to replace it, did not help. Next, I thought that the problem was in the *setTimeout* in the *do_search* search function, I removed it, but in the end it did not work.

---

P.S. I apologize for my English, I used google-translation.